# Why a variable defining with window object giving undefined value?

Tags: javascript

I have read that when we declare a variable with **window** object inside a function then it becomes a **global** variable i.e. we can access that variable outside the function.

but I am getting the problem when accessing that global variable and it is giving **undefined** as output.

Below is the code snippet:

***window.js***

```
function m(){  
    window.value=100;//declaring global variable by window object  
}  

function n(){  
    document.write("Global var value: "+ window.value);//accessing global variable from other function  
}
```

***window.html***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="window.js"> </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> This is global variable test. </p>
        <form>
            <input type="button" onclick="n()" value="Click!!"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### ***output***

**Global var value: undefined**

Please help me on this.

Comment: At no point do you call `m()` which is what sets the variable in the first place...

Answer (score 4):

> I have read that, when we declare a variable with `window` object inside a function then it becomes a global variable...

It's not a *declaration*, it's an assignment. And that matters, because it doesn't happen until/unless the step-by-step execution of the code you've written reaches that line (whereas declarations are handled in a pre-step-by-step stage [within the scope]).

The problem in your code is that your `m` function is never called, so the code in it is never run, so nothing creates the global.

A global is probably not the solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve anyway, for what it's worth. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use your .js file as like below:

```
    function m(){  
window.value=100;//declaring global variable by window object  
}  
function n(){  
m();
document.write("Global var value: "+ window.value);//accessing global variable from other function  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your `m()` function first like below to set the `variable`.

```
(function m(){  
    window.value=100;//declaring global variable by window object  
})();
```